# Tool to invoke actions in Flash swf via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flash

I have a flash swf file without access to it's source. Can I use only JavaScript to invoke/initiate the action of the flash functions within the swf file?

Or does the swf need active listeners to respond to JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot communicate with an SWF (at least an AVM2 (AS3 based) SWF) unless it has registered callback methods in it. The `ExternalInterface` class has an `addCallback()` [method](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback()) that:

> Registers an ActionScript method as callable from the container. After a successful invocation of `addCallBack()`, the registered function in Flash Player can be called by JavaScript or ActiveX code in the container.