# Javascript on embedded videos

Tags: javascript, flash

Is it possible to use javascript to seek position of videos embedded on a page (Videos from Youtube, DailyMotion, Revver, etc)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581976/tool-to-invoke-actions-in-flash-swf-via-javascript/1582011#1582011

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to read the position of progressbar of the video player it could be done, but the player (usually flash object) has to expose appropriate methods or events to javascript. The exact way of intercating with player depends on the specyfic flash object you use.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube has a [javascript API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html) which can be used to control the video playback, including seeking the position